# Sklearn Python - Difference in results between accuracy_score and roc_curve function output

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I am using logistic Regression for my analysis. My Accuracy score and AUC score are different

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(x, you, test_size=0.3,random_state=0) 

LogReg=LogisticRegrssion() 
LogReg.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred=LogReg.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)

accuracy_score=0.84
```

When I plotting Roc and Auc curve

```
y_scores_lr = LogReg.fit(X_train,y_train).decisio n_function(X_test) 

fpr, tpr, _=roc_curve(y_test, y_scores_lr) 
roc_auc_logreg =auc(fpr, tpr) 

roc_auc_logreg=0.87
```

Why there is a difference in results between accuracy_score and roc_curve function output, where I am making mistake that both of these are not matching. Any help on this to correct any error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If different metrics gave same results, there wouldn't be need to duplicate them, don't you think...?

Comment: Is these are same metrics or different. If same why am I different. Am I making any mistakes in the code

Answer (score 1):

I think what Tim is alluding to is the fact that AUC and accuracy are two different metrics, hence they yield two different results.

You can find **tons** of resources on what [accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) is and what [AUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve) is on this site or via the Google. For more information on how sklearn calculates `accuracy` or `auc`, you can always look at the source [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L115) and [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py#L39).